# Сделать выбранную форму checkbox устойчивой к обновлению страницы в браузере на Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть приложение To Do List на Vue. С помощью кнопки добавить запись, добавляется новая строка текста, каждая из которых имеет чекбокс и кнопку удалить. Моя задача: сохранять все введенные данные из форм (текст и выбран или нет чекбокс) при обновлении страницы браузера. Для этого использую mounted и watch, но получается только сохранять данные текста-чекбоксы так и не нашел пока как сохранить (неудачные попытки в коде не выкладывал). Помогите с кодом, пожалуйста.

```js
Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return{
          placeholder: 'Start typing',
          inputvalue: '',
          notes: [],
          checked: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('note')) || [];
      },
    watch: {
            notes: {
                handler: function() {
                localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(this.notes));
                },
                deep: true
            }
    },
    methods: {
        addnewtask(){
            if (this.inputvalue !== ''){
                this.notes.push(this.inputvalue)
                this.inputvalue=''
            }
        },
        removetask(index){
            if (confirm('Do you really want to delete?'))
            this.notes.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
}).mount(app)
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #030303;
    background: #3d5f82;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: solid;
}
.btn {
    color: #31d78c;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 99px;
    border: 1px solid #31d78c;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #fff;
}
.btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:rgb(231, 239, 235);
}
.btn.danger {
    color: #eb3c15;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 99px;
    border: 1px solid #eb3c15;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #fff;
}
.btn.danger:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:rgb(236, 219, 219);
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.form-control {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-control input,
.form-control select {
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    color: #2c3e50;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.card {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #fff;
}
.card.center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.list-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    transition: .22s all;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<style>
    [v-cloak] {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="app" v-cloak>
      <div class="card">
          <h1>To Do List</h1>
          <div class="form-control">
             <input
                 type="text" 
                 v-bind:placeholder="placeholder" 
                 v-model="inputvalue"
                 v-on:keypress.enter="addnewtask"
              />
              <button class="btn" v-on:click="addnewtask">Add Task</button>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <ul class="list" v-if="notes.length !== 0"...>
                <li class="list-item" v-for="(note, index) in notes" v-bind:key="note">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[note]"/>
                        <span :style="checked[note] ? 'text-decoration: line-through' : ''">
                            {{index+1}}) {{note}}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn danger" v-on:click="removetask(index)">Delete</button>
                </li>
                <hr />
                <li>
                    <strong>Total: {{notes.length}}</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div v-else>No task exist, please add first one.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script src="Vue3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну так checked тоже сохраняйте в local storage  и восстанавливайте на watch. И почему бы note не сделать объектом с полями title и checked?

Comment: @alezhu, спасибо, но уже пробовал делать идентичный код  в local storage для массива checked-не выходит и еще ломается все приложение (выдает ошибки). Можете подробнее объяснить про второе предложение сделать note объектом с полями title и checked? Я совсем еще новичок в коде и может не догоняю чего, но как я понял Вы предлагаете сделать массив note в data вместо просто массива checked и включить в него title и checked.  Хорошо бы на примере с кодом это посмотреть.

Comment: Так и не разобрался как сделать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удаляете checked

```
data(){
    return{
      placeholder: 'Start typing',
      inputvalue: '',
      notes: [],
    }
},
```

При добавлении нового значения, добавляете объект с полями title и checked:

```
    addnewtask(){
        if (this.inputvalue !== ''){
            this.notes.push({title:this.inputvalue,checked:false})
            this.inputvalue=''
        }
    },
```

В шаблоне меняете

1. note на note.title
2. checked[note] на note.checked
   :

   ```
       <li class="list-item" v-for="(note, index) in notes" v-bind:key="note.title">
           <div>
               <input type="checkbox" v-model="note.checked"/>
               <span :style="note.checked ? 'text-decoration: line-through' : ''">
                   {{index+1}}) {{note.title}}
               </span>
           </div>
           <button class="btn danger" v-on:click="removetask(index)">Delete</button>
       </li>
   ```

[Демо](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-qjtsgd?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: спасибо большое-все работает! Неделю пробовал, перечитал кучу теории, посмотрел кучу практики, но так и не смог решить сам. Можешь подсказать куда, к кому лучше пойти учиться (или может быть есть хороший материал на ютубе), что изучать конкретно, чтобы подтянуть уровень до: могу легко устроиться на позицию junior frontend?

Comment: @EvgeniyR1987  без понятия ¯\_(ツ)_/¯